# Planar Graph Isomorphism

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, knot-theory

In 1980,  [I. S. Filotti & Jack N. Mayer proved planar graph isomorphism testing](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/76553/filename/RR-0008.pdf) could be done in polynomial time.

Does anyone have an implementation of that?  I have a few billion planar graphs I'd like to sort through.  Specifically, [Gauss code loops](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GaussCodeLoops/) can be used to enumerate self-crossing closed loops. My plan is to select the permutations that give planar graphs, then to group them by graph invariants to enumerate the unique closed loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing isomorphism testing, I'd recommend using [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/index.html) as an obvious choice.  It is super fast, can find planar embeddings, and has the following quote on the webpage that suggests it may implement the algorithm you talk about:

> "There are polynomial time algorithms for many special classes of graphs (bounded degree, bounded genus, classes with excluded minors or topological subgraphs). Few of these are practical, planar graphs being a notable exception."